# How do I Pivot Vertical Data to Horizontal Data SQL with Variable Row Lengths?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

**Okay I have the following table.**

```
Name    ID  Website

Aaron | 2305 |  CoolSave1


Aaron | 8464 |  DiscoWorld1


Adriana |   2956 |  NewCin1


Adriana |   5991 |  NewCin2


Adriana | 4563  NewCin3
```

I would like to transform it into the following way.

```
Adriana  |  2956 |  NewCin1 |   5991 |  NewCin2 | 4563  | NewCin3


Aaron | 2305 | CoolSave1 |  8464 |  DiscoWorld | NULL | NULL
```

As you can see i am trying to take the first name from the first table and make a single row with all the IDs / Websites associated with that name. The problem is, there is a variable amount of websites that may be associated with each name. To handle this i'd like to just make a table with with the number of fields sequal to the max line item, and then for the subsequent lineitems, plug in a NULL where there are not enough data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the result, you will need to apply both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT functions to the data. The UNPIVOT will take the columns (ID, website) and convert them to rows, once this is done, then you can PIVOT the data back into columns.

The UNPIVOT code will be similar to the following:

```
select name,
  col+'_'+cast(col_num as varchar(10)) col,
  value
from
(
  select name, 
    cast(id as varchar(11)) id, 
    website,
    row_number() over(partition by name order by id) col_num
  from yt
) src
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (id, website)
) unpiv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83267/6). This gives a result:

```
|    NAME |       COL |       VALUE |
-------------------------------------
|   Aaron |      id_1 |        2305 |
|   Aaron | website_1 |   CoolSave1 |
|   Aaron |      id_2 |        8464 |
|   Aaron | website_2 | DiscoWorld1 |
```

As you can see I applied a `row_number()` to the data prior to the unpivot, the row number is used to generate the new column names. The columns in the UNPIVOT must also be of the same datatype, I applied a `cast` to the `id` column in the subquery to convert the data to a `varchar` prior to the pivot.

The `col` values are then used in the PIVOT.  Once the data has been unpivoted, you apply the PIVOT function:

```
select *
from
(
  select name,
    col+'_'+cast(col_num as varchar(10)) col,
    value
  from
  (
    select name, 
      cast(id as varchar(11)) id, 
      website,
      row_number() over(partition by name order by id) col_num
    from yt
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (id, website)
  ) unpiv
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (id_1, website_1, id_2, website_2, id_3, website_3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83267/7).

The above version works great if you have a limited or known number of values. But if the number of rows is unknown, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to generate the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME( col+'_'+cast(col_num as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by name order by id) col_num
                      from yt
                    ) t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'id' col union all
                      select 'website'
                    ) c
                    group by col, col_num
                    order by col_num, col
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               select name,
                col+''_''+cast(col_num as varchar(10)) col,
                value
              from
              (
                select name, 
                  cast(id as varchar(11)) id, 
                  website,
                  row_number() over(partition by name order by id) col_num
                from yt
              ) src
              unpivot
              (
                value
                for col in (id, website)
              ) unpiv
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83267/8). Both versions give the result:

```
|    NAME | ID_1 | WEBSITE_1 | ID_2 |   WEBSITE_2 |   ID_3 | WEBSITE_3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Aaron | 2305 | CoolSave1 | 8464 | DiscoWorld1 | (null) |    (null) |
| Adriana | 2956 |   NewCin1 | 4563 |     NewCin3 |   5991 |   NewCin2 |
```

Comment: I like the demos with fiddler. Question: this is not pure SQL, but slightly like a stored procedure/program right?

Comment: @Menelaos The second one would be run in a stored procedure.